# Max_wal_size setting value is not currect from the pg_settings

Tags: postgresql, settings, pg

I found that `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'max_wal_size'` and `show max_wal_size` the value is different in postgresql-9.6.6 .The value return from `show max_wal_size` is the same as the postgresql.conf what I had set . I did not run the `alter system` command to change the max_wal_size in the command line .I'v check the pg_settings the max_wal_size which source is postgresql.conf.Is there some difference between these two command ? Where can I find which value is  activated in postgresql?

Comment: please post commands you use with exact output. alse are you behind pgpool or some load balancer?

Comment: I think I had a misunderstanding from `pg_settings`.The value from the view `pg_settings` should be the `setting * unit`.And the value equal the value from `show max_wal_size`

Comment: You could write that as an answer. I'd upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value from the view `pg_settings` should be the `setting * unit`.And the value equal the value from `show max_wal_size`

Comment: I have similar problem here, but I don't understand your answer. What do you mean by pg_settings should be setting * unit ?